# Twitter Bootstrap - Button Width in Drop-down menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Fairly new to bootstrap-- but I have a button and drop down menu which is composed of an unordered list containing buttons. How would I make the button widths all the same-- or am I completely off base with my code:

Here is the code:

```
<div class="btn-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
    <a class="btn btn-large dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <i class="icon-wrench">
    </i>Admin Actions <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <button  class="btn btn-large">
                <i class="icon-plus"></i>Create Content</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button  class="btn btn-large">
                <i class="icon-wrench"></i>Edit Page</button></li>
        <li><button   class="btn btn-large">
            <i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Page</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5wqU5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add 'btn-block' to your buttons...

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-block">
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wqU5/2/