# How to fix width of drop-down button in bootrstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown list:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." id="toggleButtons1">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">SOME VERY LARGE TEXT 1</button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" value="undefined">SOME VERY LARGE TEXT 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" value="undefined">SOME VERY LARGE TEXT 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" value="undefined">SOME VERY LARGE TEXT 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" value="undefined">SOME VERY LARGE TEXT 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" value="undefined">SOME VERY LARGE TEXT 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now the problem is that the button of the dropdown, which shows the current selection increases the width according to the text inside it.
I want this button to restrict itself inside the parent div.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441887/twitter-bootstrap-button-width-in-drop-down-menu

Comment: another possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590929/setting-the-width-of-a-dropdown-list-in-bootstrap-3-0

Comment: Try the search next time, this kind of questions have for sure been asked multiple times already.